# Git warning: "Empty last update token."

Tags: windows, git, version-control, git-bash

What is the cause and resolution for the git warning message "Empty last update token."?

I have a repository, where every command prints this warning, e.g.

```
$ git status
warning: Empty last update token.
On branch foo
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/foo'.

$ git fetch
warning: Empty last update token.

$ git reset --hard
warning: Empty last update token.
Updating files: 100% (79/79), done.
HEAD is now at e1c42a2 blah

$ git prune
warning: Empty last update token.
```

The commands still seem to succeed. The warning message totally confuses external tools like git-extensions though, which shows "unresolved merge conflicts" when `git status` contains any unexpected output.

The problem only occurs with the local repository on one specific pc, but copying the .git folder to a different pc reproduces the problem.

I could delete the local copy and start fresh, but I would like to determine the cause, and perhaps even save the stashes.

Comment: A Google search for that error message brings me to https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/fsmonitor.c . This seems to be related to the fsmonitor feature. Are you using it, and do you know if it has a reset / re-initialize command?

Comment: Just a wild guess, but maybe `git fsmonitor--daemon stop` followed by `git fsmonitor--daemon start` would do the trick? And `git fsmonitor--daemon status` beforehand might give you some diagnostic information?

Comment: I did restart the problematic PC, and I was also able to reproduce the problem on another pc after copying the repository, so I do not think any current monitor thread could be the problem.

Comment: It *is* an fsmonitor issue. You might want to report it to the Git mailing list or the Windows-Git mailing list, especially if you have a way to reproduce it.

Answer (score 7):

@kaveman is right, this is evidently the new filesystem monitoring daemon that  got built into git for Windows and Mac OS in 2.37. When I enabled with `core.fsMonitor = true` in my `.gitconfig`, git 2.35.1 printed this same *Empty last update token* warning. After I upgraded to git 2.37, the warning disappeared.

Comment: Upgrading to git version 2.37 also worked on my Win 11 machine, running Ubuntu-20.04 under WSL.

Comment: Keep in mind on OSX, you probably have to install the Git-Homebrew version 'over' the Apple version: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/93002/how-to-use-the-homebrew-installed-git-on-mac

Answer (score 6):

This isn't a great answer, but it got rid of the error message for me:

Check if `core.fsMonitor` is on:

```
$ git config core.fsMonitor
true
```

And if `true`, turn it off:

```
$ git config core.fsMonitor false

$ git config core.fsMonitor
false
```

Potentially more information on this thread: https://public-inbox.org/git/4aa1293e-00b6-b9ef-efd4-cdf605db37a1@jeffhostetler.com/

Comment: If you are seeing it with "core.fsMonitor", update Git, should solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Note: on Mac, `fsmonitor` might work better with Git 2.39 (Q4 2022): by default, use of `fsmonitor` on a repository on networked filesystem is disabled.
Add knobs to make it workable on macOS.

See [commit c4f9490](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c4f94907902f18d80a78ee19983d0d02932154d7) (10 Oct 2022) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
See [commit 5aa9e32](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5aa9e3262e6ac99c1c06d7f0e0619b1ea94a9881), [commit 25c2cab](https://github.com/git/git/commit/25c2cab08f90b6251b1ace91e37f05d4cb8fcd0c), [commit 12fd27d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/12fd27df79ac5f2589b54c8f36761d066dc9a97e), [commit 8f44976](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8f44976882b77bb3b9ac0579a04ef05cbea5bdb2), [commit 6beb268](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6beb2688d33373508610b190f04721e748caa12c), [commit 508c1a5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/508c1a572d633202a220f2902c0d6b4cd1678349) (04 Oct 2022) by [Eric DeCosta (`edecosta-mw`)](https://github.com/edecosta-mw).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7b8cfe3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7b8cfe34d9b36a08214ea7e3ae82e9563188de5e), 17 Oct 2022)</sup>

> ### [`fsmonitor`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/12fd27df79ac5f2589b54c8f36761d066dc9a97e): deal with synthetic firmlinks on macOS
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Eric DeCosta</sup>

> Starting with macOS 10.15 (Catalina), Apple introduced a new feature called 'firmlinks' in order to separate the boot volume into two volumes, one read-only and one writable but still present them to the user as a single volume.
> Along with this change, Apple removed the ability to create symlinks in the root directory and replaced them with 'synthetic firmlinks'.
> See '`man synthetic.conf`'
>
> When FSEevents reports the path of changed files, if the path involves a synthetic firmlink, the path is reported from the point of the synthetic firmlink and not the real path.
> For example:
>
> - Real path: `/System/Volumes/Data/network/working/directory/foo.txt`
> - Synthetic firmlink: `/network -> /System/Volumes/Data/network`
> - FSEvents path: `/network/working/directory/foo.txt`
>
> This causes the FSEvents path to not match against the worktree directory.
>
> There are several ways in which synthetic firmlinks can be created: they can be defined in `/etc/synthetic.conf`, the automounter can create them, and there may be other means.
> Simply reading `/etc/synthetic.conf` is insufficient.
> No matter what process creates synthetic firmlinks, they all get created in the root directory.
>
> Therefore, in order to deal with synthetic firmlinks, the root directory is scanned and the first possible synthetic firmink that, when resolved, is a prefix of the worktree is used to map FSEvents paths to worktree paths.

---

In addition, Git 2.39 (Q4 2022) also enables macOS build with `sha1dc` hash function.

See [commit 3220565](https://github.com/git/git/commit/32205655dc7ce44863bf79fb05bf170d9ad6da32) (19 Oct 2022) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit cc75743](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cc7574322fbf6d43cf5f36c7e98bd2e095bc3bc7), 21 Oct 2022)</sup>

> ### [`fsmonitor OSX`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/32205655dc7ce44863bf79fb05bf170d9ad6da32): compile with `DC_SHA1=YesPlease`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Eric DeCosta</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> As we'll address in subsequent commits the `"DC_SHA1=YesPlease"` is not on by default on OSX, instead we use Apple Common Crypto's SHA-1 implementation.
>
> In [6beb268](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6beb2688d33373508610b190f04721e748caa12c) ("`fsmonitor`: relocate socket file if .git directory is remote", 2022-10-04, Git v2.39.0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7b8cfe34d9b36a08214ea7e3ae82e9563188de5e) listed in [batch #3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4732897cf0a255a23dca9e97b65cea40cd06c5a8)) the build was broken with `"DC_SHA1=YesPlease"` (and probably other `non-"APPLE_COMMON_CRYPTO"` SHA-1 backends).
>
> So let's extract the fix for this from [this thread](https://lore.kernel.org/git/c085fc15b314abcb5e5ca6b4ee5ac54a28327cab.1665326258.git.gitgitgadget@gmail.com/) to get the build working again with `"DC_SHA1=YesPlease"`.
> In addition to the fix in [1] we also need to replace `"SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH"` with `"GIT_MAX_RAWSZ"`.

---

Actually, still with 2.39 (Q4 2022), DC_SHA1 is the default:

See [commit d00fa55](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d00fa5528b44a8a4e59cb16348f2ddb46f0190ee), [commit fb8d7ad](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fb8d7add06792bd4cc0f00c032b44478b219ca90), [commit dc1cf35](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dc1cf3580e2ec7dd164c95cec2f5568beaf3324b), [commit ed605fa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ed605fa1a8a2afe47cda5f24b5059494b86379b9), [commit 84d71c2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/84d71c20214455c9c5ce9d5b4b0412f4915e650a), [commit f569897](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f569897cdac5c79639aaaa9f97207bc317e7624d), [commit 34b660e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/34b660e3e60b094cd456dbaf9484ba261a7a9faa), [commit b425ba2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b425ba2380e9b5704e2f9753b80bc85205e44274), [commit 0ced11d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0ced11d32fea5caec3f014b4e60dd197b9c8aa0f), [commit e47913e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e47913e8e29fdeaa26ccdf2626894da5283d9bd8) (07 Nov 2022) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Taylor Blau -- `ttaylorr` --](https://github.com/ttaylorr) in [commit e53598a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e53598a5ab745fb633dc99ed11cbe4b1bee066fa), 18 Nov 2022)</sup>

> ### [`Makefile`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fb8d7add06792bd4cc0f00c032b44478b219ca90): document default SHA-1 backend on OSX
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> Since [1] the default SHA-1 backend on OSX has been `APPLE_COMMON_CRYPTO`.
> Per [2] we'll skip using it on anything older than Mac OS X 10.4 "Tiger"[3].
>
> When `"DC_SHA1"` was made the default in [4] this interaction between it and `APPLE_COMMON_CRYPTO` seems to have been missed in.
> Ever since `DC_SHA1` was "made the default" we've still used Apple's CommonCrypto instead of `sha1collisiondetection` on modern versions of Darwin and OSX.
>
> 1. [6106795](https://github.com/git/git/commit/61067954ce166e8a6fbcd109376fe2d9681ca333) (`cache.h`: eliminate SHA-1 deprecation warnings on Mac OS X, 2013-05-19, Git v1.8.4-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/527b1719f583ed56653b6d296422968e86f62d59)) ([`cache.h`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/fb8d7add06792bd4cc0f00c032b44478b219ca90/cache.h): eliminate SHA-1 deprecation warnings on Mac
>    OS X, 2013-05-19)
> 2. [9c7a0be](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9c7a0beee093908e26c11e689e391f95410d35c2) (`config.mak.uname`: set NO_APPLE_COMMON_CRYPTO on older systems, 2014-08-15, Git v2.2.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/55b6dffd135b51e643f5ebbcf346453a8ceebad0)) (config.mak.uname: set `NO_APPLE_COMMON_CRYPTO` on older
>    systems, 2014-08-15)
> 3. We could probably drop `"NO_APPLE_COMMON_CRYPTO",` as nobody's likely
>    to care about such on old version of OSX anymore. But let's leave that
>    for now.
> 4. [e6b07da](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e6b07da2780f349c29809bd75d3eca6ad3c35d19) ("`Makefile`: make `DC_SHA1` the default", 2017-03-17, Git v2.13.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/48b3693d3cec7bd7996b1394a8df901d1fc26320) listed in [batch #7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ea5b2dd28f7dc6e0f331af2aad13e281e7a9a408))

---

Still on the MacOS side, Git 2.40 (Q1 2023) will stop using deprecated macOS API in `fsmonitor`.

See [commit b022600](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b0226007f0aaf448dec1defe3e44c4e3d7513aa8) (14 Dec 2022) by [Jeff Hostetler (`Jeff-Hostetler`)](https://github.com/Jeff-Hostetler).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 636de95](https://github.com/git/git/commit/636de956c4a942ab3c247eba3a6dbb3113fa7ea8), 19 Dec 2022)</sup>

> ### [`fsmonitor`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b0226007f0aaf448dec1defe3e44c4e3d7513aa8): eliminate call to deprecated FSEventStream function
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff Hostetler</sup>

> Replace the call to `FSEventStreamScheduleWithRunLoop()` function with the suggested `FSEventStreamSetDispatchQueue()` function.
>
> The MacOS version of the builtin FSMonitor feature uses the `FSEventStreamScheduleWithRunLoop()` function to drive the event loop and process FSEvents from the system.
> This routine has now been deprecated by Apple.
> The MacOS 13 (Ventura) compiler tool chain now generates a warning when compiling calls to this function.
> In `DEVELOPER=1` mode, this now causes a compile error.
>
> The `FSEventStreamSetDispatchQueue()` function is conceptually similar and is the suggested replacement.
> However, there are some subtle thread-related differences.
>
> Previously, the event stream would be processed by the `fsm_listen__loop()` thread while it was in the `CFRunLoopRun()` method.
> (Conceptually, this was a blocking call on the lifetime of the event stream where our thread drove the event loop and individual events were handled by the `fsevent_callback()`.)
>
> With the change, a "dispatch queue" is created and FSEvents will be processed by a hidden queue-related thread (that calls the `fsevent_callback()` on our behalf).
> Our `fsm_listen__loop()` thread maintains the original blocking model by waiting on a mutex/condition variable pair while the hidden thread does all of the work.
>
> While the deprecated API used by the original were introduced in macOS 10.5 (Oct 2007), the API used by the updated code were introduced back in macOS 10.6 (Aug 2009) and has been available since then.
> So this change *could* break those who have happily been using 10.5 (if there were such people), but these two dates both predate the oldest versions of macOS Apple seems to support anyway, so we should be safe.

---

With Git 2.40 (Q1 2023), use the SHA1DC implementation on macOS, just like other platforms, by default.

See [commit 35898ad](https://github.com/git/git/commit/35898ad24d83317135d7fdad601dc17375ac373e) (15 Dec 2022) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit cd2cc44](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cd2cc44c023eb92cede5849b00cdc84274885985), 26 Dec 2022)</sup>

> ### [`Makefile`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/35898ad24d83317135d7fdad601dc17375ac373e): use sha1collisiondetection by default on OSX and Darwin
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> When the `sha1collisiondetection` library was added and made the default in [1] the interaction with `APPLE_COMMON_CRYPTO` added in [2] and [3] seems to have been missed.
> On modern OSX and Darwin we are able to use Apple's CommonCrypto both for SHA-1, and as a generic (but partial) OpenSSL replacement.
>
> This left OSX and Darwin without protection against the SHAttered attack when building Git in its default configuration.
>
> Let's also use `sha1collisiondetection` on OSX, to do so we'll need to split up the "`APPLE_COMMON_CRYPTO`" flag into that flag and a new "`APPLE_COMMON_CRYPTO_SHA1`".
>
> Because of this we can stop conflating whether we want to use Apple's CommonCrypto at all, and whether we want to use it for SHA-1.
> This makes the CI recipe added in [4] simpler.
>
> 1. [e6b07da](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e6b07da2780f349c29809bd75d3eca6ad3c35d19) ("`Makefile`: make `DC_SHA1` the default", 2017-03-17, Git v2.13.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/48b3693d3cec7bd7996b1394a8df901d1fc26320) listed in [batch #7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ea5b2dd28f7dc6e0f331af2aad13e281e7a9a408))
> 2. [4dcd773](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4dcd7732db071c8e1e0466b98eaf9501f7fe1a7e) ("`Makefile`: add support for Apple CommonCrypto facility", 2013-05-19, Git v1.8.4-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/527b1719f583ed56653b6d296422968e86f62d59))
> 3. [6106795](https://github.com/git/git/commit/61067954ce166e8a6fbcd109376fe2d9681ca333) ("[`cache.h`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/61067954ce166e8a6fbcd109376fe2d9681ca333/cache.h): eliminate SHA-1 deprecation warnings on Mac OS X", 2013-05-19, Git v1.8.4-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/527b1719f583ed56653b6d296422968e86f62d59))
> 4. [1ad5c3d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1ad5c3df35aa92416443e42e718d0855abcec1d3) (`ci`: use `DC_SHA1=YesPlease` on osx-clang job for CI, 2022-10-20, Git v2.39.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bda957de7cd86933aa898351c796fd4a7d18f983) listed in [batch #6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b71552977030afd6f187c3f13e6b5c892d31a89d))